# I did have an idea about the size of an intra-galactic Space craft but

Tags: discussion

..when going to answer one post about this subject I get a panel which asks me not to give opinions and to back my answer with references etc. What?

I feel therefore I cannot answer!

Answer (score 5):

Where possible, answers here should be based on hard science and backed up with references.

In reality, we know that this cannot always be done, either because the references don't exist, or because there are restrictions on using them, but trying to provide fact-based answers is essential.

So if you have an idea about something, but it is not based on anything but speculation, then your answer would likely just get downvotes.

Key is - if you do have an idea, do a bit of research so you can back it up when you post, and that is far more likely to be successful.

Have a look at highly upvoted posts here - you will see many have diagrams, links to publications from NASA and other space agencies, and sometimes even video footage.

Comment: It is possibly worth noting that [worldbuilding.se] allows for speculative questions which have a basis in fact but don't necessarily need to be scientifically viable. There may exist a question about intergalactic spacecraft which allows on's mind to roam free.